# Magento 2 Stores -> Configuration redirects to dashboard

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.8

Getting issue after enabling `form_key` from backend.
When I am trying to open **`store > configuration`** 
from Order section it took me redirect to admin dashboard

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at - https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/22366
Body must be at least 30 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I cannot "add a comment" yet, so this is the only place I can write.

I also see this issue having performed an upgrade to 2.2.8 from 2.2.2 today, however I am being redirected to the Orders screen rather than Dashboard, and from a variety of places (including attempting store > configuration as you did, and in fact attempting to see Dashboard sends me to orders...) - it'd be interesting to know if you get the redirect from other places too (e.g. Indexer or Cache screens, where I also suffer the issue).

I have also been battling with serialization / deserialization issues as a result of the same upgrade, and wonder if there is some serialized (old style pre-Json) data in your core_config_data table somewhere that might be throwing it.

Comment: When i am trying to redirect from order section To config...that Took me to dashboard in Magento 2.2.8

Comment: Interestingly my problem was solved when I upgraded the same installation further on from 2.2.8 to 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar, 302 redirects to your admin start page from some sections. I never found the root cause but fixed when disabling admin security keys.

From terminal run 
php bin/magento config:set admin/security/use_form_key 0

You should see the keys disappear from URLs and the issue disappear.